# Use web api cookie for mvc cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a web application by using Web API 2 and MVC 5.

My app has api :
api/account/login, which is used for checking posted information and throw status 200 when an account is granted to access application.

Also, I have one view : /Home/Index which is only available to authenticated client.

Now, my approach is :

- Call api/account/login, receive the cookie thrown from that api.
- Attach thrown back cookie to browser.
- When user access /Home/Index, view is available for him/her.

**My questions are :**

**- Is my approach possible ?**

**- How can I encrypt my cookie in Web API 2 like MVC 5 does to its cookie ?**

Thank you,

Comment: Can you check my answer. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this to have a authorization server (a webAPI generating a token) and token consumption middle ware in your MVC project.IdentityServer https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3 should help. However I have done this as below

Built an authorization server using JWT with WEB API and ASP.Net Identity as explained here http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

once you do that your webAPIs startup.cs will look like below

```
/// Configures cookie auth for web apps and JWT for SPA,Mobile apps
private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

    //Cookie for old school MVC application
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        CookieHttpOnly = true, // JavaScript should use the Bearer
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,                
        LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Account/Login"),
        CookieName = "AuthCookie"
    };
    // Plugin the OAuth bearer JSON Web Token tokens generation and Consumption will be here
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),                
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTPath"])
    };

    // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

}

You can find CustomOAuthProvider,CustomJwtFormat classes here https://github.com/tjoudeh/AspNetIdentity.WebApi/tree/master/AspNetIdentity.WebApi/Providers

Write a consumption logic (i.e. middleware) in all my other APIs (Resource servers) that you want to secure using same token. Since you want to consume the token generated by webAPI in your MVC project, after implementing Authorization server you need to do below

In your MVC app add below in startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
}

private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthIssuer"];
    string audienceid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceId"];
    byte[] audiencesecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"]);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieName = "AuthCookie" , AuthenticationType=DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie });

    //// Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            AuthenticationType = "JWT",
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceid },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audiencesecret)                           
            }

        });
}
```

In your MVC controller when you receive the token de-serialize it and generate a cookie from the access token

```
        AccessClaims claimsToken = new AccessClaims();
        claimsToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessClaims>(response.Content);
        claimsToken.Cookie = response.Cookies[0].Value;               
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + claimsToken.access_token);
        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authenticateResult = await ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("JWT");
        ctx.Authentication.SignOut("JWT");
        var applicationCookieIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticateResult.Identity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        ctx.Authentication.SignIn(applicationCookieIdentity);
```

Generate a machine key and add it in web.config of your webAPI and ASP.Net MVC site.

With this a cookie will be created and [Authorize] attribute in MVC Site and WebAPI will honor this cookie.

P.S. - I have done this with a web API issuing JWT (Authorization server or Auth & resource server) and successfully able to consume in a ASP.Net MVC website, SPA Site built in Angular , secure APIs built in python (resource server) , spring (resource server), Android App.

Comment: Thank you for posing the link on my question. You've explained your answer really well. I have a quick question, How would you consume this in a win form application?

Comment: If it is a standalone application that doesn't interact with a remote database/API then the token approach won't help, if it interacts with an API then you can have one API (say AuthAPI)  that generates token and another API(ResourceAPI) that can consume the token generated by AuthAPI and fetch the data.All the methods of ResourceAPI are protected with [Authorize] attribute.Now 1)Make a login screen in winforms 2)Login button will make a AuthAPI call and fetch the token which needs to be stored in winform 3)Subsequent API calls to the ResourceAPI should add Authorization header with the token

Comment: received from previous AuthAPI call. So the whole idea is designing your winform similar to a mobile app. (Sorry for the punctuation, have to do it because of the characters limit)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the [cookie](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies) once the user has authenticated against the Account controller.

```
public class AccountController 
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Login() 
   {         
      // Your authentication logic

      var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

      var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "12345");
      cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
      cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
      cookie.Path = "/";

      responseMessage.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
      return responseMessage;
   }
}
```

To authenticate you can put the `[Authenticate]` attribute on your `Home` controller.

```
public class HomeController
{
    [Authenticate]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

The Authenticate attribute can also be applied at the Controller level if needed.

```
[Authenticate]
public class HomeController
{
}
```

You can also make your own authorization attribute if needed by overriding [AuthorizeCore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase)) and checking for a valid cookie:

```
public class CustomAuth : AuthenticationAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["CookieName"];

        // Your logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `system.web/machineKey` attributes in the web.config (or on the machines) must be equal when using this on different servers.