# User login not being authenticated using OWIN bearer tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm working with an *MVC* app. The login is handle by *Web API*.

The issue I'm facing is when I click on Login button in the *MVC* app the API is generating the **token** along with the user info. However I can't display the user information in the view.

The following code is in the `AccountController` of MVC App

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
   string token = Token.GetToken(Token.GRANT_TYPE, model.Email, model.Password, Token.CLIENT_ID, Token.CLIENT_SECRET);

  //token has the appropriate data if I debug it

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

   return View(model);
}
```

Then in the **View** I have

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <p>@User.Identity.GetUserName()</p> //this line is always blank
}
```

The **API** looks like this

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{

        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

        if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {
                    "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                },
                {
                    "userName", context.UserName
                },
                {
                    "email", context.UserName
                },
            });

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
        context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

Can someone tell me why the request is not being Authenticated? What am I missing

Comment: You say the token has the correct info but does the user principal have it at this stage? `@User.Identity` generally gets loaded from that token. There are a few ways to get it in there. As an aside, consider switching to JWT tokens. They're becoming standard now and can help simplify this.

Comment: If your Account controller is Web API, it can't return a View Object. That would mean it's a MVC Controller. Web API, and the GrantResource End point, can only return data, not a View. Please Clarify...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I call the web api `/token` in my account controller, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @Izzy, I saw that, but it's not the same at all. 1st of all, you seem to return a View, which means, to my understanding that it's not a web api. 2nd, you're not returning a token to the user. **most of all**, I'm not sure that Token is same format that you've configured your Middle Ware for.

Comment: When you configure `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, you also have configured an end point for retrieving tokens. That's in the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` of the `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`. It sets where you make http calls to get a token. Kind of similar to the Account Login method you designed.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I think I'm confusing myself with how to configure the middle. You're correct I havent configured the end point to retrieve the token as you mentioned in the comment

Comment: @Izzy, take a look at this post. It explains how  to configure JWT's, and OAuth handling of Tokens on `[Authorize]`. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx

Comment: Taiser Joudeh's post may be even better. http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/ ... and I really like his GitHub project with a fully implemented solution for getting and sending tokens https://github.com/tjoudeh/AspNetIdentity.WebApi

Comment: @Izzy, the quick overview of the Token workflow is like this: 1) you query the token endpoint and get back a bearer token. 2) Store that endpoint on your client ... in a session store, a cookie, or in something like AngularJS service. 3) When you make a request of a protected end point (Web-API with `[Authorize]` attribute, you send the token in your http header as `"Authorization: Bearer mytoken123"`

Comment: @Izzy, Tomorrow I'll re-word my answer to include this workflow. LMK if you have more questions... I suspect you will, this is very confusing when you try to wrap your mind around it the first time. I think I see from your example how you're getting stuck in the more traditional server cookies workflow.

Comment: @Izzy, it's been a while since I've implemented tokens last. I think Joudeh's solution is better starting point. He uses standard Tokens, not JWT's. But, not sure you need JWT's. they're a luxury. Most important is implementing a solution where you can get and send tokens properly. If you want to use JWT's later, we can go through Scott Allen's implementation of JWT's and add it to your solution.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate. When I call the service from a windows app will it be a similar process? In terms of sending the token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118607/discussion-between-izzy-and-dave-alperovich).

Comment: The most important piece I see missing here is the token consumption logic in your MVC application which is very well explained in Taiser's series here http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/ and here http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/. Also see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424518/use-web-api-cookie-for-mvc-cookie/38428420#38428420

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things that seem wrong to me from your example

---

### Part I: Your Login Method

Convention is to use the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` as an endpoint (`/api/token`) which ***receives credentials*** and ***returns Access Token***.

By convention, this endpoint replaces the `Login(LoginViewModel)` Method. Clearly you should not be using the `Login()` method, but I suspect you are.

- If you are using the `Login` method, it only returns your original, unaltered View Model with Credentials. Your LoginViewModel class may have a token property in it, but you are not populating it. So, the Login Method authenticates your user, but doesn't authorize them because the user will never get their Access Token.
- Your `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` Method does return a Token and populates Claims. But do you have any client logic to store the access token and send it in each request?
- Unless your Token is in a format like **JWT** (Json Web Tokens), I suspect it would be a major challenge to un-encrypt the token to access the claims (e.g. userName / email). Meaning, it wouldn't be easy for your client to extract the claims from the Access Token unless it was **JWT**.

---

### Part II: Can someone tell me why the request is not being Authenticated?

You **ARE** being authenticated. But this isn't Forms Authentication. There is no Cookie. *Razor Calls to Identity will not work when an API returns Access Tokens.*

**In your typical Forms Auth model:**

credentials are sent and validated (Authenticated). If Validation is successful, the user is Authorized (given access) with a client side cookie that has encrypted access information and claims. The **OWIN Middle-ware** reads the Cookie on each request and populates the httpContext (`Identity` is a property on the `httpContext` object.)

**Access Token work flow:**

is very similar, except, since there is no Cookie, and no connection between the API and the client View other than the data returned in View Models. The `httpContext` will not be populated except on the server side (Web API), each time the **OWIN Middle-ware** reads the access Token.

So, a Razor call to

```
@User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Will come up empty.

---

### Solution: Getting and Storing User Info on the client

If you want user information from the Server, you should cache the username (and any other info you need) on the client.

**Ways to store user info on client browser**:

- Session storage
- Local Storage
- JavaScript singleton class (like an Angular Service)

**Ways to get username**

- Store the username you get when user enters credentials (clear it if Authentication fails)
- Have a dedicated end point (API Method) to return the user info you want
- Return claims in **JWT**'s.

If you change your Token Type (in Global.asax or Startup.cs -- depending on how you have configured) to use *Jason Web Tokens*, the client will be able to un-encode your token and read the claims as **JSON** Array.

---

- **A last option:** You can use both Access Tokens AND Cookies. You can return an Access Token and create a cookie. Suppress cookie auth for Web API where ever you configure Web API.
- **A final thought:** Access Tokens are used for an extra level of security (cookies are more vulnerable). But what is your purpose in using Access Tokens? Such security is more important if your are creating a **SPA** (Single Page App) like with **AngularJS**. Otherwise, Cookie Auth is a much simpler work flow, and, unless you feel you need the extra security, cookies are preferable.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, please explain down vote. What specifically do you feel is wrong with my answer?

Comment: In our conversation, your argument against loading the principal now that he has token wouldn't work because of how/when the view is rendered. You do not mention that here. I deleted my answer because I'm focusing on JWT tokens which would require a bit of a rework that the OP didn't ask for.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, I'm not sure I understand. Please elaborate. Are you contending that the Razor code would run **after** the View is rendered?

Comment: No. You were telling me that the view itself will have been rendered before the RedirectToAction therefore setting the principal once he gets the token wouldn't work.

Comment: I was saying to set the principal so that the user context will be filled for when the view IS rendered, thus displaying the correct name.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, do we agree that the that authorization request will be made after the view renders?

Comment: Depends which view you're talking about and at what stage and why. It will be made after the login view is rendered and the form is submitted because that's what it's supposed to do. It will not be run after the Home view renders succesfully. If Home is protected and it see that it doesn't have an authenticated principal, then it'll just redirect back to login, so the point is moot.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, if you're arguing that the View will be re-rendered due to an AJAX call, I disagree. AJAX requests cannot perform a redirect, not do they re-load the orignial View. They can be used to request specific HTML, but that HTML would have to be manually added to the HTML page. So they Razor call to httpconext could not work against a populated context.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, even further, a request made in Web API would not share httpcontext with an MVC method. They are completely different frameworks. That's what RESTful means. State-less.

Comment: I never said anything about ajax nor sharing context with the webapi. And I don't see what being stateless has to do with either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118491/discussion-between-dave-alperovich-and-sinaesthetic).

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. The reason for the development of an Web Api is because of various client we have that require authentication. Including, Mobile, Web(MVC & Web Forms) and Win Forms. The aim is to have one generic place where the user authentication is managed. How will cookie Auth work with in Win Forms and Mobile.

Comment: @Izzy, just noticed the question about cookies and Win Forms and Mobile apps. The short answer is, they wouldn't mix well. Win Forms you can implement the `CookieContainer` and use `HttpClient` to make your calls. Android Java has similar constructs, though you would be re-inventing the wheel. **bearer tokens are much more natual approach**

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I want to do this: "You can return an Access Token and create a cookie." Can you point me a resource to explains how to get the token and create a cookie in the AccountController.Login() method of an ASP MVC web application, and how the token is to be extracted from the cookie to authenticate subsequent requests to Web API? I've spent nearly a week researching and can't find anything with actual code explaining the token-embedded-in-cookie approach.

Answer (score 2):

The token was obtained but the principal wasn't loaded. You'll have to load the principal onto the thread some time before the controller instantiates. If you try to set it IN the controller, the new data wont be reflected, since controller data and the view are rendered at the same time, and that includes the principal.

Since there's a redirect happening, you could use that as an opportunity to load it. In order for that to happen, you'll have to save the token either to a cookie or to the session so that it'll be available on the next request (the redirect) keeping in mind that a response has to make it back to the browser in order for it to actually store the cookie, then the followup redirect will include the cookie that was just saved. Then just plug into the pipeline somewhere before controller resolution (like in a custom http module), pull it back out, use it to build the principal and set it on the thread and it'll be present for the duration of the request.

I'd also suggest switching over to using JWT tokens. Once you learn how to make them, they're much more usable and contain more useful info... well anything you place in the claims and they deserialize directly into a ClaimsIdentity.

Alternatively, you might be able to simply save the token to an auth ticket cookie and configure OWIN to pick that up on the MVC side and build the principal for you... basically do everything I just suggested for you. I'm not that experienced with it, so I'm not sure if that would work.

Here is what the basic flow might look like. The red part is the part I think you're missing. The orange part is also missing but you can either do it by hand via custom HttpModule or configure OWIN to do it for you (i think).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the flow diagram, it makes sense, I'm currently not setting the token in a cookie or session, hence why I have no user information from what I can gather.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle both client and server login (client being the webapp calling the api and server being the api)

As @Dave mentioned you will need middleware on your client side to store the token.

For a true Restfull api you will have to store all infos client side(still webapp not user) and none on the api side.

My approach woud be to add a base controller that all your other controller will inherit of.

Where you handle user infos in Session, on login you store the token and use a custom UserManager/SigninManager and your own implementation of Identity to manage user connexion.

Usefull link on this process:

[MVC API Secure individual account](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Comment: Web API, like all restful resources, is sessionless

Comment: You do not NEED middleware to store the token. Let that be clear. That is just one way to handle it. Also, WebAPI is only sessionless if you don't use sessions. ASP.Net has sessions, therefore WebAPI has them as well. REST should be stateless but that doesn't mean all "RESTful" webservices are simply because someone calls it a REST service. WebAPI is just a framework and can be abused like any other framework.

Comment: Yes I never said it was mandatory, actually the point of my answer was to add informations on this specific case of communicating with an api with a .net mvc application, I added the link wich is the one way of implementing it.
And rest is a standard, it's up to the dev to respect it or not, but it may be good practice, I didnt' say the api don't have session, I said, to be restfull you have to not use it on the api that's all.

Comment: @GaelSa Was referring to Dave's comment on the sessionless bit

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, yes, you can hack Web API to have sessions. But that hack causes your Web API to use MVC contexts instead of http contexts. At that point there is no advantage to a Web API over just using an Action Method. The point of using Web API and bearer tokens is NOT to have your MiddleWare track users explicitly... In order to avoid a security hole.